# Matplotlib delete plot stribes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have the following issue displayed in the image below:[image: problem]

For an improved clarity I want do delete the stripes on the x axis or put them below the x axis. (Also it would be nice If you know a solution to the problem of overlapping numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined your plot and axes as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

If you want to remove the x axis tick marks you can do:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', top='off', bottom='off')
```

If you want to change the direction of the tick marks you can do:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
```

If you want to change the x axis labels then use:

```
set_xticklabels()
```

You have to pass a list of labels to use, although I'm not sure why your labels aren't evenly spaced. The documentation at the link below should help:

[matplotlib.axes documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)

Comment: Is it also possible to just have tick marks at the position of the numbers?